# Any way to serve static html files from express without the extension?

Tags: node.js, express

I would like to serve an html file without specifying it's extension. Is there any way I can do this without defining a route? For instance instead of

```
 /helloworld.html
```

I would like to do just

```
 /helloworld
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A quick'n'dirty solution is to attach `.html` to requests that don't have a period in them and for which an HTML-file exists in the public directory:

```
var fs        = require('fs');
var publicdir = __dirname + '/public';

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.path.indexOf('.') === -1) {
    var file = publicdir + req.path + '.html';
    fs.exists(file, function(exists) {
      if (exists)
        req.url += '.html';
      next();
    });
  }
  else
    next();
});
app.use(express.static(publicdir));
```

Comment: Nice.Just one question. Would this intercept all the public request.Suppose I want to serve a css in the public directory for which I will add the extension then would this break?

Comment: It will only consider requests that don't have a period in their filename. So if you serve your CSS files with a `.css` extension, there shouldn't be a problem (but it checks for the existence of a `.html` file first, if it doesn't exist it will just do nothing and let the static middleware handle it as-is).

Answer (score 74):

you can just use extension option in express.static method .

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'),{index:false,extensions:['html']}));
```

Comment: great answer dai

Comment: `app.use(express.static(<public dir>,{extensions:['html']}))` is enough, otherwise you would have to access `example.com/index.html` as `example.com/index`.

Comment: This should be the top answer. We experienced that first-hand after pushing live, an index.html that does not serve up from `/` was very unexpected.

Answer (score 4):

This single line can route all the html file extension in the public folder.

```
app.use(express.static('public',{extensions:['html']}));
```

Answer (score 3):

While Robert's answer is more elegant there is another way to do this. I am adding this answer just for the sake of completeness. To serve static files without extension you can create a folder with the name of the route you want to serve against and then create an `index.html` file in it.

Taking my own example if I wanted to serve `hello.html` at `/hello`. I would create a directory called `hello` and put an index.html file in it. Now when '/hello' is called express will automatically serve this file without the extension.

Kind of obvious as this is supported by all web frameworks but I missed it back then.

Comment: Not really feasible in larger projects

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go the reverse way like I did(serving an html file called "helloworld" as html) this is the middleware I used.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.path.indexOf('.') === -1) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  }
  next();
});

app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log('App listening on port 8080!');
})
```