# cannot set node and express to serve files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I use Windows 7. I installed nodes 0.10.12 and latest version of express and express-generator both globally. I

created a new express project named `nodetest1` and installed all dependencies succesfully using `npm install`.

Going to `http://localhost:3000/` renders `Express Welcome to Express` -so it works.

I try to use node and express as simple server now, just use some `html` files.

According to the book "Jump Start Node.js" by Don Nguyen Copyright © 2012 SitePoint Pty. Ltd. [pages 9-11] , I edited my

`app.js` file and added

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

and after

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
```

I added

```
app.get('/form', function(req, res) {
  fs.readFile('./form.html', function(error, content) {
    if (error) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      res.end();
    } else {
      res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
      res.end(content, 'utf-8');
    }
  });
});
```

Then I created a simple `form.html` file put it in the nodetest1 directory, restarted my server and in the command line I get

```
app.get('/form', function(req, res) {
TypeError : Cannot call method 'get' of undefined
npm ERR! weird error 8
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

What am I doing wrong? I just want to use simple html, not Jade.

Also do I have to edit the `app.js` for every html file I add? And where will I add the new files, in what folder?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Did you create the express app?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

Also, you can just use `res.sendFile` for this.

```
app.get('/form', function(req, res) {
  return res.sendFile('form.html');
});
```

If you are serving up a lot of static files you may want to look into `express.static` middleware.
http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.use

This will serve up all files you put in your public directory:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Directory structure:

```
|-app.js
|-public
| |-index.html
| |-form.html
```

You're **form.html** will be served to `localhost:3000/form.html`

If you wan't to serve up html files without an extension you can use the solution found in this other answer to a different question by **@robertklep**.
[Any way to serve static html files from express without the extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16895047/any-way-to-serve-static-html-files-from-express-without-the-extension)

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.path.indexOf('.') === -1) {
    var file = publicdir + req.path + '.html';
    fs.exists(file, function(exists) {
      if (exists)
        req.url += '.html';
      next();
    });
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

You'll want this to be before `app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'public'));`

---

Note: The book you mentioned was published Dec 2, 2012. Express 3 was released Oct 23, 2013 according to github. The current version is 4.8.5. You may want to use a more current reference.

Comment: `var express = require('express');
var app = express(); app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` are in the `app.js`. I put `form.html` in `public` dir and `http://localhost:3000/form.html` works. Thanks! -- Is normal that I put `http://localhost:3000/form` (no `.html` at the end) and does not work and renders `Error 404`? -- Is this a complete server? Because the book I mentioned suggests to edit `app.js` and this  [tutorial](http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/) , in Part 2 suggest to edit routes and views. Why they cant just use `public` dir?

Comment: I added to the answer some middleware you can use to achieve this. It comes from another answer on SO here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16895047/any-way-to-serve-static-html-files-from-express-without-the-extension