# Sails js route static html

Tags: static, sails.js, single-page-application, assets

I want to completely separate the client and server sides in my sails js app.

If I remove the '/' route, automatically it will serve a file named index.html from the 'assets' folder.
I want to serve another file from the assets folder, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the middlewares that sails uses

**config/http.js**

```
order: [
  'startRequestTimer',
  'cookieParser',
  'session',
  'myRequestLogger',
  'bodyParser',
  'handleBodyParserError',
  'compress',
  'methodOverride',
  'poweredBy',
  '$custom',
  'router',
  'www',
  'favicon',
  '404',
  '500'
],
```

We can see that it tries to match the current request with the `router` middleware as defined in `config/routes.js` and if none is found, tries to serve the a static file in the `www` middleware. If both fail, then a 404 is returned.

**The 'www' middleware**

The `www` middleware simply uses express's serve-static middleware.

```
www: (function() {
  var flatFileMiddleware = require('serve-static')(sails.config.paths['public'], {
    maxAge: sails.config.http.cache
  });

  return flatFileMiddleware;
})(),
```

> By default this module will send "index.html" files in response to a
>   request on a directory.

So if you want to use sail's default middlewares, then you can put your html files into `assets/index.html`, `assets/about/index.html`, and `assets/foo/index.html` which will be served for `/`, `/about`, and `/foo` respectively.

However, if you really want control over this, then you can replace the www middleware and replace it with your own middleware. Read up on sail's documentation on [middlewares](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/middleware) and [serve-static's documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static) as well.

You can check out similar questions on this topic: [Any way to serve static html files from express without the extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16895047/any-way-to-serve-static-html-files-from-express-without-the-extension)

Answer (score 1):

You can place your `Html` files in assets folder. Sails will serve the html file for requested url.

Say, you place a html file `about.html` in `assets` folder, Sails will serve it when a url `<your-domain>/about.html` is requested.

Comment: It's not working when calling <domain>/about, without the html extention.

Comment: @user3712353 You just need to place the html file in `assets/about/index.html`