# Express Static Not Working as Expected

Tags: node.js, express

I have my Node.js site running static html and my server.js file is below:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(serve('/client', {
    extensions: ['html']
}));

const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, process.env.IP || "0.0.0.0", function(){
  console.log('server is running at %s', server.address().port);
});
```

I'm expecting that when I have a URL of:

```
http://www.example.com/my-file-name
```

This is pointing to this static file:

```
http://www.example.com/my-file-name.html
```

However, I am getting the following response:

```
Cannot GET /my-file-name
```

Am I misunderstanding how Express Static works? Or do I have my server.js file mis-configured?

Updates:

• Here's a screenshot of my file system:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fyd818obfbfmdin/Screenshot%202017-05-11%2016.02.46.png?dl=0

• I removed the express-static module since it was pointed out that Express already has it bundled.

Comment: FWIW Express bundles a static file middleware (`express.static()`) that also has an `extensions` option.

Comment: Where are the desired files like `my-file-name.html` in your server file system?  Also, you should probably be using the built-in `express.static()`, not loading another module.  If express static is not finding them, then it's likely because you aren't properly specifying where to look in the server-side file system.

Comment: The file in question is in a sub-folder. Specifically this url is what I'm trying to get working: `www.example.com/blog/test-article-name`. It is a static html file in the `/blog` folder with the .html file extension. But I wan't to serve it without the `.html` extension.

Comment: Are you files actually in the absolute paths `/client` and `/blog` at the very top level of your server disk volume?  Because that's where you're telling express static to look for them.  If you want a path relative to where you server.js is located, then you need to either build the appropriate absolute path that includes the whole path or you can use a relative path that does not start with `/`.  I don't think this is a file extension issue - I think express.static isn't looking in the right place for your files.

Comment: The client folder is at the top level, but blog is nested inside of `/client`.

Answer (score 0):

The path you pass to `serve()` is the local filesystem path that is to be used as the root for serving files. If `/client` as an absolute path on your local filesystem does not exist, you should use the correct (possibly absolute) path instead (e.g. `__dirname + '/client'` if `client` is a subdirectory within the same directory as the script).

Comment: Both of those options have no effect on making the non ".html" file extension URL serve up. The `/my-file-name.html` url path works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This fix from robertklep made it work for me:

```
var fs        = require('fs');
var publicdir = __dirname + '/public';

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.path.indexOf('.') === -1) {
    var file = publicdir + req.path + '.html';
    fs.exists(file, function(exists) {
      if (exists)
        req.url += '.html';
      next();
    });
  }
  else
    next();
});
app.use(express.static(publicdir));
```

Link to the post where I got it from: [Any way to serve static html files from express without the extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16895047/any-way-to-serve-static-html-files-from-express-without-the-extension)