# Send uploaded Image in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

Have an Express application that uploads an image using Multer. What I would like to be able to do is serve that image. The challenge though is when the file is uploaded it does not save the file extension which is by designed from what I've read for security purposes. What I need to be able to do is add the correct extensions to the corresponding mime type.

**Technology**

- Express: 4.15.0
- Multer: 1.3.0
- mmmagic: 0.4.5

**File Structure**

```
root
  server.js
  /uploads
    /images
      ad58c400e67362118ac1b11f6c4b6c44
      ...
  /routes
    drinks.routes.js
    uploads.routes.js
```

Running this all through Postman. Have form elements `name`, `tagline`, `image`. If I upload "IMG_111.jpg" That image will get uploaded through Multer, validated that it's an image type, and placed in `/images/uploads` with a new name, default behavior for Multer to create uniqueness. The problem is I have the `filename` but it is not saved with an extension.

**drinks.routes.js**

```
var upload = multer({
  dest: 'uploads/images',
  fileFilter: function (req, file, callback) {
    console.log('running upload file filter');
      var fileType = file.mimetype;
      if(fileType !== 'image/png' && fileType !== 'image/jpeg' && fileType !== 'image/gif' && fileType !== 'image/jpg') {
          return callback(new Error('Only images are allowed'))
      }
      callback(null, true)
  },
}).single('image');

router.route('/').post(passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), upload, function(req, res, next){
var drink = req.body;
var drinkImage = req.file;
console.log('DRINK IMAGE', drinkImage);

Drink.createDrink(drink, drinkImage, function(err, drink, drinkImage){
  console.log('creating drink');
  if(err){
    res.send(err);
  }
    res.json(drink)
  });
});
```

So I can upload a file, validate the file, save the file with a unique name and no extension. Where I'm have difficulties is then checking the mime type of the requested image, attaching an extension and sending that back in a response.

My original thought is to create a route with the image name requested, use mmmagic to detect the mime type, add the extension and serve that file. But, all attempts at this have failed.

**uploads.routes.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var path = require('path');

var mmm = require('mmmagic');
var Magic = mmm.Magic;
var magic = new Magic(mmm.MAGIC_MIME_TYPE);

router.use(function(req, res, next){
  next();
});

router.route('/images/:filename')
  .get(function(req,res){
    var fileName = req.params.filename;
    var constructFile = function(res){
      magic.detectFile(__dirname + '/../uploads/images/' + fileName, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
        if (result == 'image/jpeg'){
      // return res.sendFile(__dirname + '/../uploads/images/' + fileName + '.jpg');
      res.send(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/../uploads/images'), {index: false, extensions:['jpg']}));
    }
  });
}

constructFile(res);
  })


module.exports = router;
```

Tried following this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16895047/any-way-to-serve-static-html-files-from-express-without-the-extension) Which lead me to `express.static`. But can't figure out at this point if I'm on the right track and just missing something or if I should be looking at this from a different angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the cleanest implementation but it does work. Took the advice off the [Multer #170](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/170) issue.

**uploads.routes.js**

```
router.route('/images/:filename')
  .get(function(req,res){
    var fileName = req.params.filename;
    function getFileType(file, done){
      console.log('GETTING FILE TYPE');
      magic.detectFile(__dirname + '/../uploads/images/' + fileName, function(err, result) {
        if (err) return done(err);

        res.setHeader('Content-Type', result)
        fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname + '/../uploads/images/', req.params.filename)).pipe(res)
    });
  }
  getFileType();
})
```

The key part that was missing was the:

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', result)
fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname + '/../uploads/images/', req.params.filename)).pipe(res)
```

So now can upload a file, validate the mime type, store as a unique name, and finally call the file name, get the check the mime type, set the content-type to the mime type and deliver to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your multer uploader first. Try this:

```
var multer = require('multer');
//This is for preventing multer from giving name without extention
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'public/files/')
},
filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
}
});
```

However if you want to still have unique name then try this:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'public/files/')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(16, function (err, raw) {
      cb(null, raw.toString('hex') + Date.now() + '.' + 
         mime.extension(file.mimetype));
    });
  }
});
var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Multer is configured in the drinks.routes.js `var upload = multer({...})`. The thing I want to avoid is using the `originalname`. Want to stick with `filename` that way files are stored uniquely to avoid duplication and errors. After some more digging it seems that the extension should be added on the frontend. Which is leading me to just construct the image with the mime type with Angular. However, haven't found a clear explanation on either A) Having extension saved (is this a security issue?) or B) Constructing the extension on the FE

Comment: Try to configure the renaming function in a different way to still have unique name, but also the file extension. I will add the example in my answer

Comment: That seems to be the way floating around, was looking up some examples yesterday afternoon and saw that implementation. Instead of trying to construct something on the route response or on the front end will just have the extension saved on upload and move on. Still trying to piece together why there was mention of security issues doing this method.

Comment: Check this page and look for this guy's comment `LinusU commented on 22 Jul 2015`. He explains everything really nicely

Comment: And there is also mentioned that files without extensions are still available in browser, because browser doesn't care about them, so basically you can add your extensions to the image path in your front end and there will be no problem.

Comment: That's what I've been looking at just got it working just now

Comment: One more easy way could be done by simply adding an extension inside your upload function if you store links to images inside your database.

Comment: Yes, I know that the extension can be added during the upload and is probably a lot less hassle. However I've been wanting to avoid having that exposed to the client. Exactly what `LinusU` stated "I would strongly recommend you not to expose user uploaded files directly to the user thought!"