# NodeJS Express - Return the JSON file of the URL path that it triggered

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, api, express

I trying to write a NodeJS project that read JSON files from the project directory and response back the JSON file data whenever, user trigger a specific URL.

For the Project below, I am able to get the JSON data response when I trigger `http://localhost:8081/api/user` in web browser.

In order to make this work I have to **explicitly hardcode** a function that response to a specific URL. For example, if I wanted to add 1 more JSON files in the `api folder` and enable user to access it, I have to **explicitly hardcode** another function just to response to different request.

```
app.get('/api/newJSONFile', (req, res) => {

       fs.readFile( __dirname +'/api/newJSONFile' +".json", 'utf8', function (err, data) {
           res.send(data);
           res.end( data );
       });

    });
```

So, after adding the code above the user will able to access the JSON file through `http://localhost:8081/api/newJsonFile`. Without the **explicitly hardcode** 
 function above user will not able to get response when launch the `http://localhost:8081/api/newJsonFile`

**My Question:**

1. Is this the only way to perform the response upon URL request? It seem inefficient, as if I have 100 JSON File then I have to **explicitly hardcode** another 100 functions.
2. What is the proper way to code the implementation?

Thank you.

**My Project Structure:**

[image]

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const fs = require("fs");


app.get('/api/user', (req, res) => {

   fs.readFile( __dirname +'/api/user' +".json", 'utf8', function (err, data) {
       res.send(data);
       res.end( data );
   });

});


var server = app.listen(8081, () => {

  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)

})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [express static middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) to serve static json files from a specified folder.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Setup express static middleware to look for files in the api directory for all requests starting with /api
app.use('/api', express.static('api') , function(req, res){
    // Optional 404 handler
    res.status(404);
    res.json({error:{code:404}})
});


var server = app.listen(8081, () => {

   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port

   console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)

})
```

You can then access your `user.json` in the folder `/api/user.json` at `localhost:8081/api/user.json`

EDIT:

If you want to be able to add multiple folders, you can create a designated `public` (you can call it anything, actually) directory and put all your top level folders there.

Consider the following JSON files stored in a nested fashion:

`/public/api/user.json`    [ One level nest in api folder]

`/public/data/config.json` [ One level nest in data folder]

`/public/data/server/config.json` [Two level nest in data -> server folder]

you can then do

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// EDIT: added options to ensure json can be accessed without extension
app.use(express.static('public',{index:false, extensions:['json']}));
app.use(function (req, res) {
    // Optional 404 handler
    res.status(404);
    res.json({
        error: {
            code: 404
        }
    });
})


var server = app.listen(8081, () => {

    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port

    console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)

})
```

and then access your files as :

`localhost:8081/api/user.json` OR `localhost:8081/api/user`

`localhost:8081/data/config.json` OR `localhost:8081/data/config`

`localhost:8081/data/server/config.json` OR `localhost:8081/data/server/config`

[Reference for options accepted by the express static middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-static#options)

---

**Additional Improvement**

NOTE: This method may accidentally expose sensitive server side configuration files [like your `package.json`] and potentially your entire codebase. *Please use this method carefully and only if you know what you are doing*.

If you do not want to create a designated directory (in this case 'public' folder) and put all your top level folders there in order to access it, you can use the code below to dynamically serve your files:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

var publicdir = __dirname + '/';

app.use(express.static(publicdir,{extensions:['json']})); //or ,{index:false, extensions:['json']}
app.use(function (req, res) {

    res.status(404);
    res.json({
        error: {
            code: 404
        }
    });
})


var server = app.listen(8081, () => {

    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port

    console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)

})
```

Comment: seem like the folder need to be hardcode too, for the '/api'. Is it possible to make it, auto detect the folder URL too? for example, I add a new folder with other json file in it, I do not need to declare another use() function.

Comment: @EricWong  Yup, you can do that but you may need to reorganise your folder structure a little bit. See my edited answer

Comment: btw, is it possible to make the URL does not need to put the file extension ".json" to load the file? for example, localhost:8081/api/user instead of localhost:8081/api/user.json

Comment: i think i found the solution, using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16895047/any-way-to-serve-static-html-files-from-express-without-the-extension

Comment: Yup, express static middleware provides the extensions option. Although the accepted answer works, the other answer which uses the extensions option would be the better way to do it.. will update my answer when I get to my laptop

Comment: seem like its a syntax error, I have help you edit the mistakes. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks, accepted your edits for the syntax and the additional method. The additional method you have added is VERY risky. It is never a good idea to expose your server root using a static middleware [Your entire codebase will become accessible through the static file service]. However, I have left the edit in place as it is in line with the question you have asked.

Answer (score 1):

You could expect file name in the url and then use just one route handler to deliver JSON files.

```
app.get('/api/:jsonFile', (req, res) => {

   fs.readFile( __dirname +'/api/' + req.params.jsonFile +".json", 'utf8', function (err, data) {
       res.send(data);
       res.end( data );
   });

});
```

Do add proper error handling like if file does not exists, then send back `404` using something like below:

```
if (!fs.existsSync(path)) {
     res.status(404).send("");
}
```

Edit:

To return pretty JSON object try using the following:

```
res.header("Content-Type",'application/json');
res.send(JSON.stringify(YOUR_JSON_OBJECT, null, 4));
```

Comment: This actually working well too, is there any method to output the JSON data which is well-formatted? I tried this > obj = JSON.parse(data); res.send(obj); < but it doesn't seem the JSON data get formatted.

Comment: @EricWong I modified my answer to send back pretty JSON. See if that works for you.

Comment: in my case, it wrote, res.send(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4)); and it didn't work out.

Comment: Are you adding `res.header` as well ?

Comment: yes, anywhere, the JSON Format Output doesn't really matter. I found that using this parameter method, if I add a new folder inside the api folder, the URL will not able load. Is there any solution to overcome this limitation?

Comment: actually I was looking for a method call the API without the need to put the file extension ".json" eg. localhost:8081/api/user , now this method is good as it does not need to be like localhost:8081/api/user.json to call the file, but the issue is it cannot access to multiple tier folder.

Comment: You can simply add more params to your route: 

`'/api/:parentDir/:jsonFile'`

Comment: It look like a hardcode method, it is possible to make it auto detect the it, instead of having us to add more parems?

Comment: You can then use nodejs `readdirsync` to read and process directories to find the json file. 
Have a look at http://researchhubs.com/post/computing/javascript/nodejs-sync-directory-search-using-fs-readdirsyn.html

Answer (score 0):

Express supports [parameters in your route](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).

So having an arbitrary string from the url is as easy as modifying your route to :

```
app.get('/api/:file', (req, res) => {

    fs.readFile( __dirname +'/api/' + req.params.file + ".json", 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        res.send(data);
        res.end( data );
    });

});
```