# Remove file extension from a localhost server without using .htaccess

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess

Let's say for example I have a localhost server running on port 3000 and the url looks like: localhost:3000/index.html, how can I remove the .html extension without using .htaccess since it's on a localhost server. If there is no way without localhost then could you give me some way I could implement .htaccess in localhost? Thank you in advance

**Edit:** It is a site made in HTML, CSS and JS. Using a server.js file to do the backend stuff.

Comment: Whats a `localhost server`? Anyway, _which_ server software are you actually using? `htaccess` is a apache thing.

Comment: How the server translates a URL into a response depends on how the server is written/configured. `.htaccess` files are a way to configure Apache HTTPD. One way you can configure Apache HTTPD is how it maps URLs with no file extension onto static files which do have a file extension. Where the server runs (e.g. localhost) is completely irrelevant. What matters is **what** server software you are using.

Comment: Just using expressjs to run the thing for testing.

Comment: @BloxOverflow — So did you [read the documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.static)? That's an extensions option there.

Comment: @Quentin I read the docs and saw it, but could you give an example statement on how to implement it? I also took a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16895047/any-way-to-serve-static-html-files-from-express-without-the-extension)

Comment: `{ extensions: ['html', 'htm'] }`

Comment: @Quentin Still don't get it ;-; could you show me where to put it in here? I tried it but didn't work.
`app.use(express.static('static', { extensions: ['html', 'htm'] }));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('home.html')
})
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Listening on port 3000!')
})`

Comment: That looks fine.

Comment: It does not work though.

Comment: How about renaming that "index.html" to "index" (without an extension) on the server side? This is pretty close to "remove extension from server".

Comment: Tried that too, didn't work either. Shall I send you the whole server.js file?
**Edit:** It's working now, I don't know how, but it just is. Thank you so much for all your help!

Answer (score -1):

Most static file servers will by default implicitly serve `index.html` without needing to specify it in the path.

So the URL `/` will serve `/index.html`, and `/somewhere` will serve `/somewhere/index.html`.
Of course this depends on the software configuration.